# Cannot create instance of type "" because one or more parameters cannot be bound to

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0, dbcontext

I'm trying to create my own Web API with .NET 6 but before putting data into the database, but I get an error

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot create instance of type 'Hotelum.HotelsSeeder' because one or more parameters cannot be bound to. Constructor parameters must have corresponding properties. Fields are not supported. Missing properties are: 'dbContext'

```
using Hotelum.Entities;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Hotelum
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

            // Add services to the container.
            builder.Services.AddTransient<IWeatherForecastService, WeatherForecastService>();
            builder.Services.AddControllers();
            builder.Services.AddDbContext<HotelsDbContext>();
            builder.Services.AddScoped<HotelsSeeder>();

            var app = builder.Build();

            // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.

            app.Configuration.Get<HotelsSeeder>(); //Error appears
            HotelsSeeder seeder = app.Services.GetRequiredService<HotelsSeeder>(); 
            seeder.Seed();
            
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            //app.UseAuthorization();

            app.MapControllers();

            app.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

I have looked for any solution but cannot find it.

Here's the class where data is

```
using Hotelum.Entities;

namespace Hotelum
{
    public class HotelsSeeder
    {
        private readonly HotelsDbContext _dbContext;

        public HotelsSeeder(HotelsDbContext dbContext)
        {
            _dbContext = dbContext;
        }

        public void Seed()
        {
            if (_dbContext.Database.CanConnect())
            {
                if (!_dbContext.Hotels.Any())
                {
                    var hotel = GetHotels();
                    _dbContext.Hotels.AddRange(hotel);
                    _dbContext.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
        }

        private IEnumerable<Hotels> GetHotels()
        {
            var hotel = new List<Hotels>();
            new Hotels()
            {
                Name = "Avocado",
                Description = "Perfect for family, chill and drinks",
                Category = "Holidays",
                IsItOpen = true,
                ContactEmail = "contact@avocado.com",
                ContactNumber = "123456789",
                Rooms = new List<Rooms>()
                {
                    new Rooms()
                    {
                        Name = "Król",
                        Description = "Dla bogatych",
                        Price = 8549098M,
                        NumberOfRooms = 1,
                    },
                    new Rooms()
                    {
                        Name = "Królowa",
                        Description = "Dla mniej bogatych",
                        Price = 89098M,
                        NumberOfRooms = 5,
                    },
                    new Rooms()
                    {
                        Name = "Standart",
                        Description = "Dla standartów",
                        Price = 88M,
                        NumberOfRooms = 25,
                    },
                },
                Address = new Address()
                {
                    City = "Wwa",
                    Street = "Poznanska",
                    PostalCode = "10-092"
                }
            };
            new Hotels()
            {
                Name = "Abada",
                Description = "Perfect for horrors",
                Category = "Horros",
                IsItOpen = true,
                ContactEmail = "contact@abada.com",
                ContactNumber = "123456789",
                Rooms = new List<Rooms>
                {
                    new Rooms()
                    {
                        Name = "Bieda",
                        Description = "Dla odważnych",
                        Price = 8M,
                        NumberOfRooms = 1,
                    },
                    new Rooms()
                    {
                        Name = "Mniejsza bieda",
                        Description = "Dla normalnych",
                        Price = 98M,
                        NumberOfRooms = 5,
                    },
                    new Rooms()
                    {
                        Name = "Bogato",
                        Description = "Dla bogatych",
                        Price = 88M,
                        NumberOfRooms = 25,
                    }
                },
                Address = new Address()
                {
                    City = "Poznan",
                    Street = "Warszawska",
                    PostalCode = "50-792"
                }
            };
            return hotel;
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried to implement it with configuration but cannot find a way to work with it, was trying to add `AddDbContext` for it either not working.

Comment: In your case, the `HotelsSeeder` class must have the `HotelsDbContext` property.

Comment: But the meaning of the line `app.Configuration.Get<HotelsSeeder>()` is not clear at all. The result of the call is not saved anywhere. Do you really want to get something from the config file? I guess this line should just be deleted.

Comment: Yes this line was deleted and I have used service provider as solution lower but thank you for comment and help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things are wrong  here, first off in your `Program.cs` . You should use DI correctly

```cs
using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var services = scope.ServiceProvider;

    try
    {
        var seeder = services.GetRequiredService<HotelsSeeder>();
        seeder.Seed();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Handle any exceptions while seeding
        Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred while seeding the database: {ex.Message}");
    }
}
```

`HotelsSeeder` should be resolved from the service provider within the scope of the application. The `using` statement is used to ensure that the scope is properly disposed of after the call to `.seed()` is done.

In your method `GetHotels()` you aren't adding the `Hotels` objects to the list `hotel` which is to be seeded.

```cs
 private IEnumerable<Hotels> GetHotels()
 {
     var hotel = new List<Hotels> {
     new Hotels()
     {
         Name = "Avocado",
         Description = "Perfect for family, chill and drinks",
         Category = "Holidays",
         IsItOpen = true,
         ContactEmail = "contact@avocado.com",
         ContactNumber = "123456789",
         Rooms = new List<Rooms>()
         {
             new Rooms()
             {
                 Name = "Król",
                 Description = "Dla bogatych",
                 Price = 8549098M,
                 NumberOfRooms = 1,
             },
             new Rooms()
             {
                 Name = "Królowa",
                 Description = "Dla mniej bogatych",
                 Price = 89098M,
                 NumberOfRooms = 5,
             },
             new Rooms()
             {
                 Name = "Standart",
                 Description = "Dla standartów",
                 Price = 88M,
                 NumberOfRooms = 25,
             },
         },
         Address = new Address()
         {
             City = "Wwa",
             Street = "Poznanska",
             PostalCode = "10-092"
         }
     },
     new Hotels()
     {
         Name = "Abada",
         Description = "Perfect for horrors",
         Category = "Horros",
         IsItOpen = true,
         ContactEmail = "contact@abada.com",
         ContactNumber = "123456789",
         Rooms = new List<Rooms>
         {
             new Rooms()
             {
                 Name = "Bieda",
                 Description = "Dla odważnych",
                 Price = 8M,
                 NumberOfRooms = 1,
             },
             new Rooms()
             {
                 Name = "Mniejsza bieda",
                 Description = "Dla normalnych",
                 Price = 98M,
                 NumberOfRooms = 5,
             },
             new Rooms()
             {
                 Name = "Bogato",
                 Description = "Dla bogatych",
                 Price = 88M,
                 NumberOfRooms = 25,
             }
         },
         Address = new Address()
         {
             City = "Poznan",
             Street = "Warszawska",
             PostalCode = "50-792"
         }
     }};
     return hotel;
 }
```

**Additional**

I don't see the connection string being added here:
`builder.Services.AddDbContext<HotelsDbContext>();`

either add it there or in your `HotelsDbContext` under the overridden method `OnConfiguring`

Comment: Thanks that fixed it. I implemented `using` and it worked as it looks much cleaner. Need to read more documentation about it..

`builder.Services.AddDbContext<HotelsDbContext>();` it's already in Program but thank you to have a look on it.